# How can I safely store my IOTA seed?

Tags: seed, security

I currently store my seed in a plain text file, backed up on a USB drive, which is a security risk. What is the safest way to store my seed since there is no IOTA hardware wallet available yet?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For digital storage, I would recommend using an offline password manager such as Keepass which can encrypt your key behind a password.

For paper storage, it may be good to print out a copy of your seed in a QR code or otherwise stored and printed out and kept in a safe or safety deposit box.

For hardware storage, hopefully options arrive soon such as Ledger or Trezor.

Comment: ... and rather not use an online QR generator ;)

Comment: Good point Ghanima! For all seed related topics, never use any online generators.

Comment: Additionally I recommend adding 2-factor authentication to any exchange or online account that may interface with your real world bank account or soft wallet for additional security. Using KeePass for those online account credentials wouldn't hurt either.

Comment: Paper storage of seed does not really help ... How do you generate a receive address to deposit funds?

Comment: Paper storage isn't meant for day to day use, it's meant for peace of mind to the seed owner in case they lose their digital records.

Comment: Hi. Also think about a georedundant backup of your seed. Just in case of fire or something like that.

Answer (score 7):

What works best for me is storing the seed encrypted in a [KeePass](https://keepass.info) database file (or the offline password manager of your choice) on my computer and on an USB-Stick **in another place** (backup in case of fire, theft, ...).

#### Hardware Wallets

Having IOTAs on a Ledger Nano or Trezor would be great and they (Ledger or Trezor or both) will add IOTA eventually.

Infos/speculation about [Ledger](https://www.reddit.com/r/Iota/comments/6l106s/ledger_nano_s_support_for_iota/) and [Trezor](https://www.reddit.com/r/TREZOR/comments/6yd10x/trezor_and_iota_miota_support/) adding/not adding IOTA:

- [Trezor](https://www.reddit.com/r/TREZOR/comments/6yd10x/trezor_and_iota_miota_support/)
- [Ledger](https://www.reddit.com/r/Iota/comments/6l106s/ledger_nano_s_support_for_iota/)